# Run command only once when request with .getJSON in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to make a web interface which display the serial output from my Arduino using Pyserial. I am using Ajax ($.getJSON) to update my HTML string.

The problem I have now is that every time I request my JSON data, it also initialise my `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.wchusbserialfa140',9600)`, which makes the query slow and prohibit real-time update of serial outputs.

my code are as following:

I am trying my best to only execute `serial.Serial()` once.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.status = False


@app.route('/')
def template():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/result')
def serial_monitor():   
    #connect to serial port for once
    if g.status == False:
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.wchusbserialfa140',9600)
        g.status = True
        result = str(ser.readline())
        voltage = {'value':result}
    else:
        result = str(ser.readline())
        voltage = {'value':result}
    return jsonify(voltage)
```

My javascript:
I am using `setInterval` to repeat it automatically.

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/result', function(data)
    {$('#voltage').text(data.value);});
```

I have been trying to learn to make my little web interface and Stackoverflow has been great help to me. I have searched and tried hard to solve this problem, but I think it is worth reaching out now.
Thank you all in advance !!

---

Edited:

I have hacked it a bit to make it do what I want to do for now.
However, I am planning to use a form to get the port value from user before running `serial.Serial` line. I am still looking at `session/global variable` route.

```
global ser
ser = serial.Serial('port',9600)    


@app.route('/')
def template(): 
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/result')
def serial_monitor():   
    result = str(ser.readline())
    voltage = {'value':result}
    return jsonify(voltage)
```

Comment: OK! no problem. Sorry I am still fairly new to the community.

Comment: Great! and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was the solution I found.

By setting the global variable status correctly (inside the function), I can now run any code for once only.

```
@app.route('/')
def template():
    return render_template('index.html')

status = False
@app.route('/result')
def serial_monitor():   
    global status
    #connect to serial port for once
    if status== False:
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.wchusbserialfa140',9600)
        status = True

    result = str(ser.readline())
    voltage = {'value':result}
    return jsonify(voltage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe keep `ser` as a global variable (although this can be a problem if you use multiple process based workers) so you don't have to open it every time, just `seek` or whatever is required to get into the correct state (I know nothing about `serial` so that may or may not make sense). Or maybe `voltage` can also be global and constantly updated in a background thread so that the `serial_monitor` function only has to read the latest value of a variable.